# Not using the $GOPATH specified in "go env"

Tags: go

I've got

> export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/go

in my .zshrc.

When trying to build a project with the following:

> sudo go build -o /usr/bin/

I get a

```
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/foo/bar" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/foo/bar (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/JoahJoah/go/src/github.com/foo/bar (from $GOPATH)
```

I am assuming the "(from $GOPATH)" means the path is whatever I've set my $GOPATH variable to. And

> go env

outputs the following:

```
GOPATH="/Users/Johannes/Documents/go"
```

The "Documents" part of the path seems to be omitted when using go build.

Is build using a GOPATH from somewhere else?

Comment: Are you by any chance running `go build` with a differnet user (e.g. `root`)? Different users have different environments.

Comment: Is the package listed as not found one of yours?

Comment: @Eric, no it's not my own package.
@i

Comment: @icza I'm running build with the same user as far as I can tell

Comment: @BitterJohnBob Did you `get` the package?

Comment: use  ***go get -u github.com/foo/bar***  in order to download the missing repository.

Comment: Actually, since I'm trying to build to /usr/bin/, I am running the build cmd with sudo. I'm guessing this means the command is being run by root?

Comment: Yes it is. You should have installed go in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @EricFortin Thank you, that solves it.

Comment: Do not use sudo !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was running the the command

```
$ sudo go build -o /usr/bin/
```

with `sudo` prefixed, it was running as the `root` user, causing a different `$GOPATH` to be used.

As Eric said, I should instead build to `/usr/local/bin` where `sudo` can be omitted.

```
$ go build /usr/local/bin
```

Works!

Comment: You can also run it with `sudo -E`, which retains your existing environment variables for the command.  That said, you are correct, you should not need to run it via `sudo`.